# Line numbers for large(ish) continuous two-column document?

Tags: xetex, paracol, lineno

I have a ~30 page translation thesis where around 15 pages are in two columns with Chinese on the left and English on the right. Preferably I want line numbers for both columns on each side of the page corresponding to the Chinese and English lines.

This is the structure I've been using to achieve this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[switch,modulo]{lineno}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Unnumbered text

\section{Translation}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{linenumbers}
佐作防獲出境禁治弾豊原能載。生解公読囲団交各致米国意形京聞資読県江。労表震推榛手世速酒話学目力年科写誰。紳今綱愛合住掲年火数司際投問月購企真。諭風援読成提応愛藤析窃権室県。疑期質活岐並選探護出禁渡抗安右特報香。断用長全結防払警反入楽万木。極聞責改八並稿機電厚見屋練込車。供局戦今返資者町盗施家覇飛。

第子著疎帖喜断署明問田胸長打図開。栄紀通安治勝円防記座衝辞面派万察要本作費。思紀新問伝裁今命婦関時勤。歴歩致点方政上野余連界関玲法。鳥給申選化屋尾予府明国負時。仲闘先族三胸逮禁広来供苦療覧。社断年能人約利文入各健月発真農聞案。宇国物惑昨布稿柴社話征面場験各育位仰。木真落芸応択人社図一利命治図整天集成。

記隼計舞索新生馬茨最添並制投悩。備阪訃登潟興反最原最女護座事動学所。毎闘経局第落的断暮化佐和路導南無尾。本標含江分走海政左落転続勝住撮類族難。百毎全討暮変局木容郡部式。福毎盛表必桐経方重報必隆対審話割樫鍛。読能更後行国芸毎欧因事食賃注球探。元部逆供管就賄鈴毎千障航伝島。掃者手坂平福吉存際将断訳頃営報。
\end{linenumbers}

\switchcolumn

\begin{linenumbers}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{linenumbers}
\end{paracol}

\section{More Unnumbered Text}
More unnumbered text

\end{document}
```

[image]

So aside from the `switch` not really doing anything, this method works until around 3 pages of content when I tested it on a macbook, desktop pc and on overleaf. Any more than 3 pages it just takes wayyy too long to compile. I've had a 10 page document compiling for 24hrs running at 90C before I gave up on it.

I've tried splitting up the `linenumbers` environments instead of one big block that it has to number as well as using `pagewise` so it doesn't get up to thousands of lines; nothing's really made a significant enough difference to do a larger document though.

I'd appreciate any help with this.